# Core ML giving same prediction every time

Tags: coreml, turi-create

So I used turicreate to create a handwritten-digit recognition model using famous MNIST Dataset with enough amount of data to train the model...

But When I'm deploying the model in ios project, it always predicts same output (i.e. 1) with probability of 1.0 whereas other probabilities are too less.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you don't preprocess the input images on iOS the same way as they were preprocessed by the model. In the case of Turi Create and Core ML, these tools should do this for you automatically (especially when you use Vision to drive Core ML).

But as you've not given any details about exactly how you're using the Core ML model, it's impossible to provide a solution to your question.

Comment: Thankyou for the response... Actually I'm using Vision and coreML framework (code snippet attached)... but it still gives me same output as of 1.0.

Comment: do {
let image = UIImage(named: "8a.jpg")

let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: DigitsClassifier().model)
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: myResultsMethod)

    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
//    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: url)
try handler.perform([request])

}
catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}